# how can I put shadow and gradient effects on solid gauge in hightcharts?

Tags: highcharts, gauge

I am learning about highcharts. 
I want to put inner shadow effect and gradient on solid gauge chart in highcharts as a images below.
It doesn`t matter inner shadow position.
Have a good day.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linear gradients in your js like below

```
stops: [
        [0.5, {
          linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y1: 0,
            y2: 1
          },
          stops: [
            [0, '#0000ff'],
            [1, '#b2b2ff']
          ]
        }]        
      ]
```

```js
$(function() {

  var gaugeOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'solidgauge'
    },
    title: null,
    pane: {
      center: ['50%', '85%'],
      size: '140%',
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: {
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
      }
    },
    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      stops: [
        [0.5, {
          linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y1: 0,
            y2: 1
          },
           stops: [
            [0, '#0000ff'],
            [1, '#e3e3f4']
          ]
        }]        
      ],
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorTickInterval: null,
      tickPixelInterval: 400,
      tickWidth: 0,
      title: {
        y: -70
      },
      labels: {
        y: 16
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          y: 5,
          borderWidth: 0,
          useHTML: true
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // The speed gauge
  $('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 200,
    },

    series: [{
      data: [120],
    }]

  }));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div style="width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```